# Python-Requests how does verify parameter work? SSL Certificates

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, openssl, ssl-certificate

I know in python-requests you can send your certificate via verify parameter.

Something like this:

```
url = requests.get('someurl', verify='certifacate.pem')
```

So I understand TLS handshake protocol does follow:

```
The 'client hello' message
The client initiates the handshake by sending a "hello" message to the server. The message will include which TLS version the client supports, the cipher suites supported, and a string of random bytes known as the "client random.
```

Then we have the server hello message that lets client know what cipher suite to use.

```
The 'server hello' message: In reply to the client hello message, the server sends a message containing the server's SSL certificate, the server's chosen cipher suite, and the "server random," another random string of bytes that's generated by the server.
```

In my code using wireshark I've identified that server requests `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

[server hello screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KbfL.png)

I am confused, what are we sending in .certificate.pem file

From my understanding premaster secret it when the client sends one more random string of bytes, the "premaster secret." The premaster secret is encrypted with the public key and can only be decrypted with the private key by the server. (The client gets the public key from the server's SSL certificate.)

and as for session keys it is when both client and server generate session keys from the client random, the server random, and the premaster secret. They should arrive at the same results.

is it the `premaster secret`, or is it the `session keys` that we are sending as certificate.pem in verify parameter with request?

Do we generate these by using crypto algorithm since server is requesting `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` - we could replicate the output using the same algorithm using crypto library and pass it into requests? Is this the purpose of verify parameter?

The site I am currently trying to reach has SSL Certificates etc and it only accepts certain client certificate. I am trying to understand if verify is the correct parameter I should be using.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "verify" argument has nothing to do with client-side certificates. It's your root certificate which can be used to verify the authenticity of the server-side certificate. If you don't want to verify it, you can use on your own risk verify=False .

For client-side certificates, you need to use the "cert" argument: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates . Example:

```
requests.get('https://example.org', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
```